# loading ajax data in jquery ui modal (after submit)

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I would like to pass data from a input form to my codeigniter controller, then return a view via JSON that will then be opened in a jquery ui dialog modal...phew!

It isn't working though.  On submit, it refreshes the page, and no alerts work either (if I put it at the beginning of the findcat() function).

Here is my Javascript function:

```
function findcat(){
    var valinput = $('#category_form').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: 'http://rickymason.net/omnia/ajax/findcategory',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { valinput: valinput },
        success: function(content){
            $('#category_modal').html(content['content']);
            $('#category_modal').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Hello',
                modal: true,
                height: 350,
                resizable: false 
            });
        return false;
        }
    });  
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="cus_input">
    <form id="category_form" onsubmit="return findcat();">
        <input type="text" id="category_input" name="category_input" placeholder=" Find Category"/>
        <input type="image" id="category_submit" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>img/board/icons/add.jpg" id="homeSubmit" value="X"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

my controller is just a mockup to try and send some sort of content back:

```
    public function findcategory()
    {
        $page['content'] = 'hello-testing';
        return json_encode($page);
    }
```

Comment: why you are not using a submit button?

Comment: I wanted an image. for some reason ive been under the assumption that `input type='image'` shared the same properties as `type='submit'` ... I've tried onclick and onsubmit

Comment: `type='image'` is a submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `return false;` is used to stop the form from submitting, its in the wrong place. It should be directly in `findcat` as you have it it is in the ajax success function.

```
function findcat(){
    var valinput = $('#category_form').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: 'http://rickymason.net/omnia/ajax/findcategory',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { valinput: valinput },
        success: function(content){
            $('#category_modal').html(content['content']);
            $('#category_modal').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Hello',
                modal: true,
                height: 350,
                resizable: false 
            });
        }
    });  
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this answer helped move me into the right direction.  The `return false` being out of place was a stumbling block for sure.  After solving that, I actually just removed `onsubmit` from the html and used jquery instead: `$('#category_form').live('submit', function(){ `

Answer (score 2):

what I am not understanding is that why you are not using submit button on your form, and the **codeigniter** controller should `echo` and not `return`. here's a solution for you, regardless to your form.

**Jquery:**

```
function findcat(){
    var valinput = $('#category_form').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: 'http://rickymason.net/omnia/ajax/findcategory', //you can use site_url here whic is better for you
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { valinput: valinput },
        success: function(content){
            $('#category_modal').html(content.content);//not content['content'] 
            $('#category_modal').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Hello',
                modal: true,
                height: 350,
                resizable: false 
            });
        }
    });  
    return false; //should be in your function scope and not the ajax scope
}
```

for your controller:

```
public function findcategory()
    {
        $page['content'] = 'hello-testing';
        echo json_encode($page); // echo and not return for codeigniter
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who happens upon this question..here is my solution in thanks to the above comments.

Regarding the page submission and reload.

Jquery's `.live` will take care of it.  In your JS, simply add the following,

`$('#category_form').live('submit', function(){`

in front of your function. This will catch your submit, run the function, then reload the page.  To prevent the reload, at the end of the function, add `return false;`

Regarding the Modal and AJAX problem...In my original code, didn't, "prep" the dialog.

I didn't realize it due to my novice programming ability, but you need to first set up your dialog div with the following code:

```
$('#category_modal').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Hello',
    modal: true,
    height: 350,
    resizable: false
});
```

After that, use `$("#category_modal").dialog("open");` to "activate" it following the ajax request.

```
$('#category_form').live('submit', function(){
    var valinput = $('#category_input').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: 'http://rickymason.net/omnia/ajax/findcategory',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { valinput: valinput },
        success: function(content){
            $('#category_modal').html(content['content']);
            $("#category_modal").dialog("open");
        }
    });  
    return false;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: .live has been replaced with .on since version 1.9 of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Your form is likely doing a POST which is causing the refresh.

Take

```
onclick="return findcat();
```

out of the form tag and just put it on an a tag.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return findcat();">Click</a>
```

Comment: would you recommend then removing the form entirely?